# Preview for JSF pages with JBoss Visual Page Editor

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jboss

I have installed the JBoss Tools under Eclipse Mars (on Ubuntu Linux).
I am getting the following error, when I am opening an .xhtml which contains JSF content.

org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.XulRunnerException: You currently have Visual editor configured to have better HTML5 experience. If you want to see preview for JSF pages please change Visual Editor Browser Engine to JSF option in Visual Page Editor Preferences and restart Eclipse.

Under the preferences (JBoss Tools -> Web -> Editors -> Visual Page Editor -> General) the "Visual Editor Browser Engine" part is inactive.

How could I enbale it to be able to select the "JSF (use XulRunner)" radio button?

Comment: This functionality is very limited and only works for core jsf tags (old?) richfaces ones. I doubt it will be supported in the future. I would personally not rely on it and just use a server to render the output... auto refreshing is currently supported in all browsers